# hiding div until fully loaded and adding fade effect on js onclick slider

Tags: javascript, image, fade

I've never written codes but I'm building my own photography page. It's a simple idea; just an onclick slideshow. I could accomplish that by creating a div containing the images and using js for the onclick effect. However, I can see all the images loading before the slides hide behind the 1st image and was wondering if there's anyway to hide the div until the content is fully loaded. Also, I'd like to add a fade ou/in effect between each image. Can someone give me a light on it? My code until now is:

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.middle {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="middle">
<p><img src="header.jpg" width="131" height="21" alt="guilimora" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="text-align: center"></span></p>

<div id="imgs">
  <div align="center">
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/01-yankees bitch.jpg" alt="img1" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/02-where the sun shines best.JPG" alt="img2" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/03-keep on rolling.jpg" alt="img3" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/04-534 am.JPG" alt="img4" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/05-penguin smokes.jpg" alt="img5" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/06-quaint.jpg" alt="img6" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/07-downtown mary.JPG" alt="img7" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/08-untitled.jpeg" alt="img8" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/09-14190012.jpg" alt="img9" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/10-30470064.JPG" alt="img10" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/11-30460001.JPG" alt="img11" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/12-no trees.JPG" alt="imh12" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/13-little you or smaller I.jpg" alt="img13" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/14 - salvation.jpeg" alt="img14" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/15-afterlight-343.jpeg" alt="img15" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/16 afterlight-233 2.jpg" alt="img16" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/17 80760026.JPG" alt="img17" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/18 49750012.jpg" alt="img18" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/19 nope.JPG" alt="img19" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/20 30470138.JPG" alt="img20" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/21 93470016.JPG" alt="img21" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/22 babe the beer.jpg" alt="img22" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/23 08450037.jpg" alt="img23" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/24 ny.jpg" alt="img24" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/25 - bruised benja.jpg" alt="img25" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/26 - madam m.jpg" alt="img26" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/27 51770018.JPG" alt="img27" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/28 23700024.jpg" alt="img28" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/29 49630021 trat.jpg" alt="img29" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/30 afterlight-324.jpeg" alt="img30" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/31 IMG_1078 trat.jpg" alt="img31" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/32 05810018 copy.jpg" alt="img32" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/33 - wanna go wanna go wanna go.jpg" alt="img33" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/34 46080021.jpg" alt="img34" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/35 Image-1-1.jpg" alt="img35" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/36 Image-1-11 copy.jpg" alt="img36" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/37 30460024.JPG" alt="img37" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/38 smoking on my way to.jpg" alt="img38" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/39 where does she go.jpg" alt="img39" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/40 IMG_1264.jpg" alt="img40" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/41 44170017.JPG" alt="img41" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/42 49750004.jpg" alt="img42" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/43 30470029 trat.jpg" alt="img43" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/44 afterlight-266.jpeg" alt="img44" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/45 91930027.JPG" alt="img45" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/46 91930008 copy.jpg" alt="img46" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/47 49750028.jpg" alt="img47" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/48 93470001.jpg" alt="img48" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/49 afterlight-32.jpg" alt="img49" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/50 03140034.JPG" alt="img50" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/51 04500006.jpg" alt="img51" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/52 30470008.jpg" alt="img52" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/53 Image-1.jpg" alt="img53" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/54 handsome julio.jpg" alt="img54" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/55 30470046.JPG" alt="img55" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/56 80760027 copy.jpg" alt="img56" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/57 30470019 5.jpg" alt="img57" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/58 0283035.jpg" alt="img58" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/59 30470080.JPG" alt="img59" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/60 IMG_3936.jpg" alt="img60" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/61 sf.jpg" alt="img61" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/62 01360034.jpg" alt="img62" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/63 afterlight-332.jpeg" alt="img63" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/64 afterlight-264.jpeg" alt="img64" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/65 afterlight-237.jpeg" alt="img65" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/66 30470106 copy.jpg" alt="img66" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/67 unti.JPG" alt="img67" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/68 04470013.jpg" alt="img68" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/69 80770023.JPG" alt="img69" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/70 afterlight-347.jpeg" alt="img70" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/71 ntitled.jpg" alt="img71" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/72 DSC03987 2.jpg" alt="img72" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/73 80760030 copy.jpg" alt="img73" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/74 afterlight-244.jpg" alt="img74" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/75 i67487664.jpg" alt="img75" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/76 DSC02973.JPG" alt="img76" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/77 80760029 copy.jpg" alt="img77" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/78 IMG_1347 2.jpg" alt="img78" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/79 IMG_1068.JPG" alt="img79" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/80 IMG_2219.JPG" alt="img80" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/81 30460025.JPG" alt="img81" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/82 03170008.jpg" alt="img82" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/83 CIMG0062 trat.jpg" alt="img83" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/84 IMG_1058 3.jpg" alt="img84" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/85 afterlight-338.jpeg" alt="img85" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/86 49750024.jpg" alt="img86" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/87 untitled.jpg" alt="img87" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/88 IMG_1775 trat.jpg" alt="img88" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/89 30460023.JPG" alt="img89" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/90 IMG_1271 trat 1.jpg" alt="img90" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/91 afterlight-306 2.jpeg" alt="img91" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/92 DSC04375.jpg" alt="img92" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/93 death and all the rest.jpg" alt="img93" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/94 afterlight-284.jpeg" alt="img94" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/95 DSC03209.jpg" alt="img95" height="500" width="auto"/>
  <img src="../PHOTOGRAPHS/96 74860030 trat.jpg" alt="img96" width="auto" height="500" class="imgs"/>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var port_imgs, i;
    window.onload = function () {
            //get all the images in "#imgs"
        port_imgs = document.getElementById("imgs").getElementsByTagName("img");
           //loop through, hiding them all
        for (i = 0; i < port_imgs.length; i++) {
            port_imgs[i].style.display = "none";
                    //wire up the click event and do the magic
            port_imgs[i].onclick = (function (k) {
                var r = function () {
                    this.style.display = "none";
                    if (k >= port_imgs.length) { k = 0 }
                    port_imgs[k].style.display = "block";
                };
                return r;
            })(i+1);
        }
            //un-hide (display) the first image so we're all set to go
        port_imgs[0].style.display = "block";
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mind using jQuery? I can probably give you an easy solution with jQuery because it has built in animation effects and JavaScript doesn't, although it is capable, it's a lot more code than I'm willing to do. :P

Comment: Not at all!! I can give it a try.

Comment: That's exactely the effect I'm going for, but it only fades when the page loads (now showing div contents when fully loaded!!). But when I use the onclick to change the pictures, it slides without the fade.

Comment: Oh, I thought you just wanted the fadein to hide the FOUC. Ok, it'll be a minute.

Comment: I was thinking maybe to simplify things I could help you construct a bxSlider instead. Self written script is always the best way to learn, but if your primary goal is to display your art, then using a plugin will save you time and grief. I know that I could probably resolve your problems eventually, but I'm confident I can help you in less time with bxSlider. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

This version is based on the plugin [bxSlider](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4). It's a bit buggy but it's very versatile and been around for a while. From experience, I advise against using the minimized version (`jquery.bxslider.min.js`). Instead use the developer's version (`jquery.bxslider.js`). The solution consists of 2 files:

1. bx.html (file and name are optional of course)
2. bxmod.css (required but name optional)

The original stylesheet `jquery.bxslider.css` has relative URLs referencing some background images that aren't needed, as well as some borders, and box-shadowing that don't coincide with the "minimalist theme". `bxmod.css` reflects those changes.

See comments for additional details on finer grain control like speed and custom styles.

```css
/* This is bxmod.css, 
** copy and paste into a separate file
** and place it in the same  directory 
** where bx.html is located. 
*/

@charset "utf-8";

/** bxMod -=- Modified bxSlider Style
 * bxSlider v4.2.5
 * Copyright 2013-2015 Steven Wanderski
 * Written while drinking Belgian ales and listening to jazz

 * Licensed under MIT (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
 */

/** VARIABLES 
===================================*/

/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
  padding: 0;
  *zoom: 1;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.bxSlider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.bxSlider {
  list-style: none;
}
.bx-viewport {
  /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}
/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
  /* -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc; */
  /* border: 5px solid #fff; */
  /* background: #fff; */
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  width: 100%;
}
/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
  min-height: 50px;
  /* background: url('images/bx_loader.gif') center center no-repeat #ffffff; */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}
/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
  background: #666;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus {
  background: #000;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
  left: 10px;
  /*  background: url('images/controls.png') no-repeat 0 -32px; */
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:focus {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
  right: 10px;
  /*  background: url('images/controls.png') no-repeat -43px -32px; */
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:focus {
  background-position: -43px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
  display: none;
}
/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
  text-align: center;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 11px;
  outline: 0;
  /* background: url('images/controls.png') -86px -11px no-repeat; */
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:focus {
  background-position: -86px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  outline: 0;
  /* background: url('images/controls.png') -86px -44px no-repeat; */
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:focus {
  background-position: -86px -33px;
}
/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
  text-align: left;
  width: 80%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
  right: 0;
  width: 35px;
}
/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
  width: 100%;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
  font-size: .85em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BxSlider -=- Minimal | bx.html</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bxmod.css">
  <style>
    /* Styles Optional */
    /* Eliminates the blue select background */
    ::-moz-selection {
      background: none;
    }
    ::selection {
      background: none;
    }
    /* Resets */
    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: small-caps 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0 solid transparent;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
    }
    /* Demo styles */
    body {
      background: #000;
      color: #FFF;
      margin-left: 1em;
    }
    a:visited {
      color: grey;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <!-- Header Optional -->
    <h1>BxSlider -=- Minimal</h1>
  </header>

  <ul class="bxSlider">
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x281/000/fff.png&text=500x281" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x375/0ff/111.png&text=500x375" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x500/fc0/00e.png&text=500x500" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x625/0f0/f00.png&text=500x625" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/500x719/fff/000.png&text=500x719" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/demos/lena.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/04/TCF_centre.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://wanderingvegans.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/himejijo1.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>

  <footer>
    <!-- Footer Optional -->
    <p>This demo is an answer to a <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534871/hiding-div-until-fully-loaded-and-adding-fade-effect-on-js-onclick-slider/32536751#32536751'>question posted on Stackoverflow</a>
    </p>
    <p>bxSlider is responsive, so it usually isn't neccessary to set the dimensions on images.</p>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var bx = $('.bxSlider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        speed: 500, // Inc/Dec speed of fade
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true, // If animated height changes not desired set to false
        adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500 //Inc/Dec speed if above option is true
      });
      $('.bx-wrapper').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        bx.goToNextSlide();
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

### OLD

The gallery wasn't centered so I centered it for you, if it doesn't go well with your plans, you can just delete or comment out that potion in your `<style>` block. Notice at the very end of the `</script>` block you'll see:

`window.onload = init(1000, 1000);`

You can adjust the delay (1st number) and fadeIn (2nd number) times, they are in milliseconds so right now it's set to delay for 1 second and fadeIn will take 1 second to complete.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Centering the gallery - Optional */
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #ext {
      display: table;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px auto;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #imgs {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .middle {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #set img {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="middle">
  <p>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x50/000/fff.png&text=HEADER" alt="guilimora" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><span style="text-align: center"></span>
  </p>
  <main id="ext">
    <section id="imgs">
      <div id="set">
        <img id="i1" src="https://placehold.it/500x281/000/fff.png&text=FIRST" />
        <img id="i2" src="https://placehold.it/500x281/048/Fee.png&text=SECOND" />
        <img id="i3" src="https://placehold.it/500x281/fa8/375.png&text=THIRD" />
        <img id="i4" src="https://placehold.it/500x281/9a7/a10.png&text=FOURTH" />
        <img id="i5" src="https://placehold.it/500x281/fd3/b0d.png&text=FIFTH" />
        <img id="i6" src="https://placehold.it/500x281/fff/000.png&text=LAST" />
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var spd = 1000;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var init = $('#set img:first-child'),
        set = $('#set img');

      init.one('load', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(spd);
      });
      set.click(function(spd) {
        var imgs = set.size();
        var fwd = $(this).next();
        fwd = fwd.index() == -1 ? init : fwd;
        $(this).fadeOut(spd - 250);
        setTimeout(fwd.fadeIn(spd), 250);
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: This is great!! I applied the onload fade for subpages with this code. Thanks!! I used the css class .middle to center everything, gallery included (don't know if it's the best way, but it works fine). I deleted yours just because it messed with my slider position, but thanks for keeping that in mind! All that's left to do is to add the fade to each image in the slider.

Comment: @GUILIM Just finished take a look

Comment: I must be doing something wrong...I id'd all the images and added the fade script part. Now the page shows all images at once. Should I keep the js slide code and put your fade code after/before it?

Comment: Yeah for now. After work, if someone else hasn't come up with a better solution, I'll try to find one. I'll upvote your question and hopefully it'll attract more members to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, man! I really appreciate it! I could get a display just like this example (http://chad-moore.com), without the fade between pics. I'm happy with it, and maybe in some time try to come up with something. I took a look at bxslider and they all contain buttons and those dots under the images. I'm going for a more minimalistic display, no distractions from the photographs. You were of great help!! Once again, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @GUILIM ok, it's ready to go, I just thought of something, I use https throughout my code as a habit. So keep that in mind if you use http. Let me know if you have any problems and/or questions. Good luck to, sir.

Comment: @ze00ne Hey 01, thank you so much for time, help and availability!! I'm facing some difficulties in achieving the desired final result and can't commit much time to this. I was pretty happy with what I came up with your help, but I was viewing it only in Safari and Chrome and my laptop screen. Once I loaded it on a widescreen desktop, the result was not the same. I forgot about the responsive part. So I reckon I'll get some budgets from some web designers. It's a simple idea, so I'm hopeful it wouldn't cost me that much. Thanks a bunch, again!! And good luck to you too, man!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code inside style. Change the time from 2s to whatever suites you.
Hope this helps.

```
img{
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
   opacity: 1;
  }
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in 1 forwards;
}
```

Here is the changes inside your code. Please change the image path

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .middle {
    text-align: center;
  }

  img {display: none;}

  @keyframes fadeIn {
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  img {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in 1 forwards;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body class="middle">
  <!-- <p><img src="header.jpg" width="131" height="21" alt="guilimora" /></p> -->
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <span style="text-align: center"></span>
  </p>

  <div id="imgs">
    <div align="center">
      <img src="img/1.png" alt="img1" height="500" width="auto" />
      <img src="img/2.png" alt="img1" height="500" width="auto" />
      <img src="img/3.png" alt="img1" height="500" width="auto" />

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var port_imgs, i;
      window.onload = function() {
        port_imgs = document.getElementById("imgs").getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (i = 0; i < port_imgs.length; i++) {
          port_imgs[i].style.display = "none";
          port_imgs[i].onclick = (function(k) {
            var r = function() {
              this.style.display = "none";
              if (k >= port_imgs.length) {
                k = 0
              }
              port_imgs[k].style.display = "block";
            };
            return r;
          })(i + 1);
        }
        port_imgs[0].style.display = "block";
      }
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, Neyazul. I put it in style like you said and when I load it I get a blank page instead.

Comment: please check now. Just change the path for the images.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but by path you mean the src?

Comment: I wish...just don't know what to change it into. All the imgs are located in a separate file

Comment: My header(homepage) and contact links are actually image files with hotspots on them since I'm using a specific font that's not included in the browsers. Both these images were affected by the img display none, so I put div in imd in your css code. Now the page loads the header and contact images, but the slide is blank. Once again, change the path into what?